# Nodejs with mongoose getting error :- E11000 duplicate key error collection:

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have many collections in my database in which I am removing the indexes when the indexes are present. Bellow is my code in which I am removing the indexes.

```
module.exports = async () => {
    const connect = async () => {
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

        mongoose
            .connect(DB_URL, {
                keepAlive: true,
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
            })
            .then(async () => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error when trying to connect to MongoDB: " + err);
                console.log("failed to connect to mongodb, retrying...");
                connect();
            });

        mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
        mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);

        loadModels();
        await removeUnusedIndexes();
        await resetDatabaseWithDefaultValues();
    };
    connect();

    mongoose.connection.on("error", console.log);
};

removeUnusedIndexes = async () => {
    let counterIndexes = await CounterModels.collection.getIndexes();
    let deviceIndexes = await DeviceModels.collection.getIndexes();
    let guestIndexes = await GuestModel.collection.getIndexes();
    if (counterIndexes) {
        for (var key in counterIndexes) {
            if (key === "id_1_reference_value_1") {
                CounterModels.collection.dropIndex(key, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error in dropping index!", err);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (deviceIndexes) {
        for (var deviceIndexesKey in deviceIndexes) {
            if (deviceIndexesKey === "userName_1") {
                DeviceModels.collection.dropIndex(
                    deviceIndexesKey,
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error in dropping index!", err);
                        }
                    },
                );
            }
            if (deviceIndexesKey === "email_1") {
                DeviceModels.collection.dropIndex(
                    deviceIndexesKey,
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error in dropping index!", err);
                        }
                    },
                );
            }
        }
    }

    if (guestIndexes) {
        for (var guestIndexesKey in guestIndexes) {
            if (guestIndexesKey === "email_1") {
                GuestModel.collection.dropIndex(
                    guestIndexesKey,
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error in dropping index!", err);
                        }
                    },
                );
            }
        }
    }

    await DeviceModels.syncIndexes();
    await CounterModels.syncIndexes();
    await GuestModel.syncIndexes();
};
```

And one more issue when the server is starting for the first time after removing the database its give namespace error ns not found

To fix this issue I had to remove the removeUnusedIndexes function and then it worked
Is there any other issue in my code becuase every thing is been done with proper async processes.